# Как перевести JSON в CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv

Имеется файл JSON с разной вложенностью и неоднородной структурой:

```
{
   "item1":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"},
         "props3": "string_value" },
    "item2":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"},
         "props3": "string_value" }
    }
```

То есть, у каждого предмета есть ряд характеристик, которые могут быть словарем, списком или строкой.

Мне нужно превратить это в CSV подобного вида:

```
item_name | props1 | props2_key1 | props2_key2 | props2_key3| props3

item1     | list   | value1      | value2      | value3     | string
item1     | list   | value1      | value2      | value3     | string
```

Есть ли простые варианты сделать это?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas | conda install pandas

json_data = {
   "item1":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"},
         "props3": "string_value" },
    "item2":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key4":"value4", "key5":"value5", "key6":"value6"},
         "props3": "string_value" }
}

pd.json_normalize(json_data, sep="_").to_csv("/path/to/result.csv", index=False)
```

PS `json_data` - должен быть словарем, соответственно если у вас данные хранятся как JSON строка или как JSON файл, то сначала необходимо спарсить JSON в словарь (`dict`).

пример:

```
In [118]: print(pd.json_normalize(data, sep="_").to_csv(index=False))

item1_props1,item1_props2_key1,item1_props2_key2,item1_props2_key3,item1_props3,item2_props1,item2_props2_key4,item2_props2_key5,item2_props2_key6,item2_props3
"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]",value1,value2,value3,string_value,"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]",value4,value5,value6,string_value
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, к сожалению получаю ошибку : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @Lumxi, см. обновленный ответ...

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем то, что нужно. В моем случае для разных item все ключи в json одинаковые. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы в первом столбце таблицы были конкретные предметы, в шапке ключи, а все остальные поля заполнялись по сопоставлению. Соответственно, ключи объединяются в названии с группами. Как в примере

Comment: @Lumxi, мой ответ отвечает на ваш вопрос и правильно работает для приведенного в вопросе примера данных. Если вы не учли какие-то детали в примере данных, то советую открыть новый вопрос и учесть эти детали в __воспроизводимом__ примере данных в новом SO вопросе. И кстати, чтобы поблагодарить авторов ответов на SO придумали систему голосования и принятия ответов ;)

Comment: Да, вопрос был не совсем корректно составлен, согласен