# Как перевести JSON в CSV (вер.2)?

Tags: python, json, csv

Более корректно составил вопрос ([пред. вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1216751)), чтобы не было двойственной трактовки.

Имеется файл JSON с разной вложенностью и неоднородной структурой:

```
{
   "item1":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":"value"},
         "props3": "string_value" },
    "item2":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":"value"},
         "props3": "string_value" },
    
    "item3":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":"value"},
         "props3": "string_value" },
   
    "item4":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":"value"},
         "props3": "string_value" },
    
    "item5":
        {"props1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         "props2": {"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":"value"},
         "props3": "string_value" }
    }
```

То есть у каждого предмета есть ряд характеристик, которые могут быть словарем, списком или строкой. Ключи внутри массивов предметов одинаковы.

Мне нужно превратить это в CSV подобного вида (в первом столбце название предмета, в шапке ключи):

```
item_name | props1 | props2_key1 | props2_key2 | props2_key3| props3

item1     | list   | value       | value       | value     | string
item2     | list   | value       | value       | value     | string
item3     | list   | value       | value       | value     | string
item4     | list   | value       | value       | value     | string
item5     | list   | value       | value       | value     | string
```

Есть ли простые варианты сделать это?

Comment: [Как проверить JSON из вопроса...](https://www.google.com/search?q=validate+json+online)

Comment: Да, исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

res = (pd
       .concat([pd.json_normalize(data[key], sep="_").assign(item_name=key) 
                for key in data.keys()],
               ignore_index=True)
       .sort_index(axis=1))
res.to_csv("/path/to/result.csv", index=False)
```

промежуточный результат (DataFrame):

```
In [144]: res
Out[144]: 
  item_name              props1 props2_key1 props2_key2 props2_key3        props3
0     item1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]       value       value       value  string_value
1     item2  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]       value       value       value  string_value
2     item3  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]       value       value       value  string_value
3     item4  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]       value       value       value  string_value
4     item5  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]       value       value       value  string_value
```